# Zeta Function : Identify This Variant of an $L $- Series

Tags: reference-request, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

This is my first question on Math.SE ; if I am wrong somewhere , please correct me

I believe that there are not any mentioned variations of a **Zeta** function of this form :

> Where, $ w $ is a **constant** real, imaginary, or complex number ,
>
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ \frac{1}{n^s +w} \quad or \quad  \  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s +w} \  \ , \ w \in\mathbb{C} $$

**My Question**

> **1)** Has there been any research into this variation of a zeta function ?  Any books,texts,papers or webpages I can refer to to ?
>
> **2)** Does anyone know , off-hand , of how the zeros of this L-series and other L-series compare or any general properties of their convergence
>
> **3)** As unlikely as it may be, does there exist an analytic continuation to an L-function that this series relates to?

I understand that this may not be considered a traditional L-series at all but I ask because it seems that this variation of an L-series could give some interesting results .

Hope someone can guide me on the right path ...

Comment: Appreciate the edit HK, hope that helps me get an actual answer. Otherwise I have a lot of work ahead. =)

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that this could be construed as a variant of Weierstrass's functions, which gives lot's of other interesting relations.

Sorry next time ill just think about it before posting. Question can be closed! thanks.